# How to output variables to a rich text box one after the other in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
void ClearAllRichtextboxes()
{
    richTextBox3.Clear();
    richTextBox5.Clear();
    richTextBox6.Clear();
    richTextBox9.Clear();
    richTextBox10.Clear();  
}

ClearAllRichtextboxes();

if (comboBox5.Text == "Primer")
{
    richTextBox5.Text = "This is the number of primer tins" + primer.ToString();
    richTextBox6.Text = "This is the cost of the primer tins" + primercost.ToString();
}

if (comboBox3.Text == "Matt")
{
    richTextBox10.Text = "This is how many 2.5 tins of paint are needed: " + val44.ToString();
    richTextBox9.Text = "This is the matt cost" + valmatt.ToString();
}

if (comboBox3.Text == "Vinyl ")
{
    richTextBox10.Text = "This is how many 2.5 tins of paint are needed" + val44.ToString();
    richTextBox9.Text = "This is the of vinyl cost" + valmatt.ToString();
}

if (comboBox3.Text =="Silk")
{
    richTextBox10.Text = "This is how many 2.5 tins of paint are needed" + silkval.ToString();
    richTextBox9.Text = "This is the cost: " + valcostsilk.ToString();
}
```

Currently I am inserting text into multiple textboxes, instead I would like to output variables in one rich text box - by appending the strings.

Comment: The answers below already explain how you could concatenate two strings, using `+` operator and `string.Format`. You could also use the [`stringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder) class - which is slightly more efficient when you are doing multiple concatenations.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `richTextBox.Text` with the new information. If you want to append the new strings to what is already there use "+". You can save the string as its own variable if it helps.

```
richTextBox.Text = "First segment.";  
richTextBox.Text = richTextBox.Text + " Second segment.";
```

More info about string concatenation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like string formatting to help space the strings with spaces.

something like

```
richTextBox1.Text = String.Format("This is the number of A in B: {0}\r\n This is the number of X in Y: {1}", output1, output2);
```

\r\n indicates a new line, you can find more information about the String.Format() method on msdn:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should always use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: richTextBox9.Text = "This is the cost: " + valcostsilk.ToString.enviroment.newline(); Is this right?

Comment: @NelJ It would look more like this, `richTextBox.Text = "This is the cost: @`,  then adding `richTextBox.Text  = richTextBox.Text.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine());` That will replace '@' with a new line.

Comment: @NelJ Please select an answer in the future to avoid unnecessary traffic to this question